# I'm getting an error when trying to POST a new user to my my cUrl testing enviroment in php

Tags: php, json, curl

im new and trying to learn cURL in php but when trying to POST my new made user to my testing enviroment i get an error.

I've tried debugging and looking for various things but couldn't find anything in specific that was wrong. I tried googling as well but all the answers i found made no sense enter

```
string(830) "{"status":400,"error":"There was a problem in the JSON you submitted [92677fc5f9526c8878a88c61e3ca5a27]: unexpected characters after the JSON document () at line 1, column 1 [parse.c:618] 
in '--------------------------7c5256387e2a9ed5\r\nContent-Disposition: 
attachment; name=\"name\"\r\n\r\njohn jeff\r\n-------------------------

-7c5256387e2a9ed5\r\nContent-Disposition: attachment; 
name=\"email\"\r\n\r\nhelloyes@hotmail.com\r\n-------------------------

-7c5256387e2a9ed5\r\nContent-Disposition: attachment; name=\"phone\"\r\n\r\n09009090\r\n-------------------------

-7c5256387e2a9ed5\r\nContent-Disposition: attachment; name=\"companies\"\r\n\r\nLandstede\r\n-------------------------

-7c5256387e2a9ed5\r\nContent-Disposition: attachment; name=\"user_id\"\r\n\r\n420\r\n--------------------------
7c5256387e2a9ed5--\r\n"}"
```

```php
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://api.intercom.io/users");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    if (isset($_POST['unsubscribed_from_emails'])) {
        $post = ['name' => $_POST['name'],
            'email' => $_POST['email'],
            'phone' => $_POST['phone'],
            'companies' => $_POST['companies'],
            'user_id' => $_POST['user_id'],
            'unsubscribed_from_emails' => $_POST['unsubscribed_from_emails']
        ];
    } else {
        $post = ['name' => $_POST['name'],
            'email' => $_POST['email'],
            'phone' => $_POST['phone'],
            'companies' => $_POST['companies'],
            'user_id' => $_POST['user_id']
        ];
    }
  //var_dump($post);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post);  //Post Fields
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

    $headers = [
        'Authorization:Bearer <MYKEYYOUCANTSEE>',
        'Accept: application/json',
        'Content-type: application/json',
    ];

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);

    $server_output = curl_exec($ch);

    curl_close($ch);

  //  var_dump($server_output);
}
```

I just want the user to be added to the enviroment but nothing happens. Only when i var_dump'd to find the problem i got that errormessage.

Answer (score 0):

You need to `json_encode()` the $post data.

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($post));  //Post Fields
```

Comment: After looking into the error and changing some stuff, it did indeed work but i still got another error "errors":[{"code":422,"message":"invalid companies data structure: must be an array"}]}" i'm using intercom as an enviroment which i forgot to mention

Comment: @Joëllijtsman This is related to the Intercom API validation, `companies` is an array, instead of a single value.

Comment: Thank you, it works now. I've never posted a question before because i thought it would take to long but this was the fastest i've been helped ever!  thanks!

Comment: See an example here: https://developers.intercom.com/intercom-api-reference/reference#user-model